Issue with the ic_launcher.xml stored in res/mipmap-anydpi-v26
I have recently identified in the Android Studio Logcat an issue when I run my app from Android Studio to my device or when I relaunch the installed app on device after closing it. Please how can this been resolved?
Below the message within the Logcat:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.compagny_name.app_name:mipmap/ic_launcher with resource ID #0x7f0f0000
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:207)
    at android.content.res.Resources.fetchDrawableFromFutureCache(Resources.java:2751)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1064)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:1048)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:987)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:758)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setIcon(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:322)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setIcon(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:755)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setDefaultIcon(PhoneWindow.java:1884)
    at android.app.Activity.initWindowDecorActionBar(Activity.java:3575)
    at android.app.Activity.getActionBar(Activity.java:3508)
    at com.compagny_name.app_name.ui.container.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:433)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8270)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4085)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4277)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.compagny_name.app_name:mipmap/ic_launcher with resource ID #0x7f0f0000
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/mipmap-anydpi-v21/ic_launcher.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0f0000
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1039)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:825)
    at android.content.res.Resources$submitToFuture.call(Resources.java:2856)
    at android.content.res.Resources$submitToFuture.call(Resources.java:2838)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.app.Application.getResources()' on a null object reference
    at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.<init>(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:165)
    at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.<init>(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:152)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromTag(DrawableInflater.java:170)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:143)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1426)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1385)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:1071)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1010)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:825) 
    at android.content.res.Resources$submitToFuture.call(Resources.java:2856) 
    at android.content.res.Resources$submitToFuture.call(Resources.java:2838) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)

This is the code within the onCreate() method of the main Activity:
MainTheme() {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
          .fillMaxSize()
          .padding(0.dp)
          .background(Color.Transparent)
          .border(
              width = 0.dp,
              color = Color.Transparent,
              shape = RectangleShape
           ),
          shape = RectangleShape,
          color = Color.Transparent,
          contentColor = contentColorFor(Color.Transparent),
          tonalElevation = 0.dp,
          shadowElevation = 0.dp,
          border = null,
   ) {

    ....

    }
}

Here is the hierarchy of res folder:

ic_launcher.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
    <monochrome android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>

Device used:
Samsung Galaxy S10 with Android 12
Settings:
Android Studio --> Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 RC
SDK Build-Tools --> 34.0.0
AGP --> 8.4.0-rc02
Kotlin --> 1.9.23
Compose --> BOM 2024.04.00 | Compiler 1.5.11
Dagger --> 2.51.1
Min SDK --> 26
Compile SDK --> 34
Target SDK --> 34

Within the 5 folders mipmap-xxx (mipmap-mdpi, mipmap-hdpi, etc.) all the ic_laucher files should have the PNG extension and not WEBP as previously defined in my app.
